# Angular on IE8, display data in select element doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

i try to contstruct a formulary with angular but displaying data in select element doesn't work ...

formulary.cs.html:

```
    <table style="display: inline-block; float: left; max-width: 510px;">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="question in group.questions">
            <td>{{question.name}}</td>
            <td>
                 <div ng-switch on="question.control" style="display: inline-block;">
                     <div ng-switch-when="input">
                          <input type="text" style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}" placeholder="{{question.default_value}}" maxlength="{{question.max_length}}" />
                     </div>
                     <div ng-switch-when="textarea">
                      <textarea style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}" placeholder="{{question.default_value}}"></textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}" />{{question.default_value}}
                     </div>
                     //MY PROBLEM HERE !
                     <div ng-switch-when="select">
                          <select style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}">
                                                <option ng-repeat="choice in question.default_value" value="{{choice.value}}">{{choice.name}}</option>
                          </select>
    
                          <select style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}" ng-model="question" ng-options="choice.value for choice in question.default_value">
                          </select>
    
                      </div>
                      <div ng-switch-when="p">
                           <p style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}"><b>{{question.default_value}}</b></p>
                      </div>
                      <div ng-switch-default>
                           <!-- default action -->
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </td>
             <td>
                  <div ng-if="question.unity_variable == true">
                       <select>
                           <option ng-repeat="unit in question.unity">{{unit.value}}</option>
                       </select>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-if="!question.unity_variable">
                       {{question.unity}}
                  </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

I ve looked at [Using AngularJS, how do I bind a <select> element to an attribute that updates via a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276339/using-angularjs-how-do-i-bind-a-select-element-to-an-attribute-that-updates-v)

in my browser, the label is displayed but not the options in the select.

on the left, method :

```
<select style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}" ng-model="question" ng-options="choice.value for choice in question.default_value">
</select>
```

on the right , method :

```
<select style="width: {{ question.size }};" data-isnull="{{question.isnull}}" name="{{question.dbcolumn}}" id="{{question.dbcolumn}}">
      <option ng-repeat="choice in question.default_value" value="{{choice.value}}">{{choice.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Can you help me to find my error, please ? THX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dont' use `ng-repeat` with `select/option`. The correct usage, described [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:select) is:

```
<select ng-model="form.question"
    ng-options="choice.value as choice.name for choice in question.default_value">
</select>
```

In order for the selected options to show correctly the `choice.value` part must equal the value defined by `ng-model` (in the previous example `form.question`). I don't know your model, let's consider this:

```
question.default_value = [
    {name: "Alpha", value: "a"},
    {name: "Beta",  value: "b"}
];
```

If `form.question === "a"`, the 1st option is selected; if `form.question === "b"` the 2nd, and so on. You may select the entire object:

```
<select ng-model="form.question"
    ng-options="choice.name for choice in question.default_value">
</select>
```

In this case initialize the `form.question` as:

```
form.question = question.default_value[0];
// the index, in this example 0, is that of the selected element
```

In this case the objects must be equal with `===`; it is not enough for their properties to match.

Comment: thx but it the same like i said and show to the left part of the image... so same result

Comment: ok, it was my model who created an error (not question but choice)