# Display multiple values in a select, one item by one item

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have the following json syntax:

```
{
    "count": 90,
    "results": [
     {
         "tra_keywords": [
             "car",
             "plane",
             "Bike",
             "boat"
             ],
         "tra_title": "Jack"
     },
     {
         "tra_keywords": [
             "blue",
             "red",
             "green",
             "silver"
             ],
         "tra_title": "Averell"
     },
     {
         "tra_keywords": [
             "square",
             "column",
             "square",
             "line"
         "tra_title": "Joe"
     }
     ]
```

}

I would like to display all my tra_keywords in a select.
I use this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="rechercheKeywords" ng-model="rechercheKeywords" ng-options="resultats.tra_keywords for resultats in resultatsJSON.results"></select>
```

It works but my select display all my keywords in the field. Select display is:

```
first option:     car,plane,Bike,boat
second option:    blue,red,green,silver
...               square,column,square,line
```

I would like to have this one by one. Select display i would like:

```
first option:      car
second option:     plane
...                Bike
                   boat
                   blue
                   red
                   green
                   silver
                   square
                   column
                   line
```

How can i do that ? I think my ng-options is incorrect. Thanks

I receive my data with:

```
myApp.controller("myappCtrl",   ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('../testANGULAR/json/flux.json')
     .success(function(data){
      scope.resultatsJSON=data;
})....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS, how do I bind a <select> element to an attribute that updates via a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276339/using-angularjs-how-do-i-bind-a-select-element-to-an-attribute-that-updates-v)

Comment: Show how you receive data.

Comment: Do you want to show all tra_keywords from all your results objects ?

Comment: yes from all my results objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    "count": 90,
    "results": [{
      "tra_keywords": [
        "car",
        "plane",
        "Bike",
        "boat"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Jack"
    }, {
      "tra_keywords": [
        "blue",
        "red",
        "green",
        "silver"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Averell"
    }, {
      "tra_keywords": [
        "square",
        "column",
        "square",
        "line"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Joe"
    }]

  };

  $scope.getKeywords = function() {

    var keywords = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.data.results, function(obj) {


      angular.forEach(obj.tra_keywords, function(keyword) {

      
        if (keywords.indexOf(keyword) < 0)

          keywords.push(keyword);

      });

    });

    return keywords


  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">


    <select class="form-control" id="rechercheKeywords" ng-model="rechercheKeywords" ng-options="r for r in getKeywords()"></select>

    <p>Selected: {{rechercheKeywords}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer works, thanks, but i missed to say i have multiple results and want to display all. Not only results[0]

Comment: @Davy can you please udpate your question how exactly looks your json and whar do you want to have is your drop down

Comment: topic updated with multiple results in json and what i want to have in my selec

Comment: @Davy just last one do you want to have multiple selects on page for each node or one select contains all keywords from all tra_keywords

Comment: I want to have only one select who contains all keywords from all my tra_keywords

Comment: @Davy in that case you can extract all tra_keywords from your json before you bind it to select please see update answear

Answer (score 0):

You're right, your `ng-options` is incorrect. It should be:

```
ng-options="keyword for keyword in resultatsJSON.results[0].tra_keywords"
```

EDIT:

Reading your answer to one of the comments, if you want to create a list from all the results, then you need to flatten the data. `ng-options` expects an array of items to iterate over, or an object - to iterate over properties.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yo8v83C8lgtfnzUbZoc1?p=preview) with how to flatten

Comment: Ok, it works fine for my first results (results[0]). But like you said, how to flatten the data to display the other results ?

Comment: By iterating over the `results` and collecting all the `tra_keywords` into an array (de-duplicating, if needed).

Comment: well, i try many solutions to correctly flatten my tra_keywords array without success. I already use the angular-filter (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) in my project who have some interesting filters (flatten ,map) but i always fail to use it the proper way.

Comment: Updated the answer with a plunker

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem, thanks to all, specially sss and New Dev

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    "count": 90,
    "results": [{
      "tra_keywords": [
        "car",
        "plane",
        "Bike",
        "boat"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Jack"
    }, {
      "tra_keywords": [
        "blue",
        "red",
        "green",
        "silver"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Averell"
    }, {
      "tra_keywords": [
        "square",
        "column",
        "square",
        "line"
      ],
      "tra_title": "Joe"
    }]

  };

  $scope.getKeywords = function() {

    var keywords = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.data.results, function(obj) {


      angular.forEach(obj.tra_keywords, function(keyword) {

      
        if (keywords.indexOf(keyword) < 0)

          keywords.push(keyword);

      });

    });

    return keywords


  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">


    <select class="form-control" id="rechercheKeywords" ng-model="rechercheKeywords" ng-options="r for r in getKeywords()"></select>

    <p>Selected: {{rechercheKeywords}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```